# XmlReader resolves DTD entities on read, can this be disabled?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have an XML document that defines entities

```
<!DOCTYPE resources [
    <!ENTITY EntityOne "The First">
    <!ENTITY EntityTwo "The Second">
]>
```

...and subsequently uses those entities in the body of the document.

```
<resources>
    <string name="r1">&EntityOne; is getting mapped to the string/string>
    <string name="r2">&EntityTwo; is also getting mapped to the string</string>
</resources>
```

However, when I read in the document using XmlReader, the entities always get subsituted in the body with their text, i.e, &EntityOne; appears as "The First" in the xml body.  Is there any way I can stop this from happening so that the entities are retained?

Comment: The XML reader you get back from `XmlReader.Create` will expand entities, but if you construct an `XmlTextReader` explicitly it will not expand text entities by default (this can be controlled with the `EntityHandling` property). Unfortunately this setting is not exposed on either `XmlReaderSettings` or the base `XmlReader`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As correctly pointed out in comment, `XmlReader` class does not have public API to handle this, unlike old `XmlTextReader` which has `EntityHandling` property. If you cannot switch to `XmlTextReader` - you can use reflection to set private field of implementation returned by `XmlReader.Create` to achieve this result. Obviously it's not that great idea to rely on private implementation details, but in case you have no choice - you can do it like this:

```
var settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;                        
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(yourXml), settings)) {
    // get private field
    var eh = reader.GetType().GetField("entityHandling", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    // prevent expansion of DTD entities, char entities are still expanded
    eh.SetValue(reader, EntityHandling.ExpandCharEntities);
    while (reader.Read()) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```